# Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'p-galleria'

Tags: angular, primeng

I must be doing something stupid as I can't find this problem anywhere else.
I'm trying to use Galleria from PrimeNG but I can't get past the basics.
I am using lots of other PrimeNG components with no problem.

I have an Angular project.

In my app.module.ts I have:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {ApplicationRef, DoBootstrap, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import {AutoCompleteModule} from 'primeng/autocomplete';
import {AccordionModule} from 'primeng/accordion';
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/button';
import {FileUploadModule} from 'primeng/fileupload';
import { GalleriaModule } from 'primeng/galleria';

import {NgbDropdownModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {HeaderComponent} from './header/header.component';
import { RecipeListComponent } from './recipes/recipe-list/recipe-list.component';
import { RecipeDetailComponent } from './recipes/recipe-detail/recipe-detail.component';
import { RecipeItemComponent } from './recipes/recipe-list/recipe-item/recipe-item.component';
import { ShoppingListComponent } from './shopping-list/shopping-list.component';
import { ShoppingEditComponent } from './shopping-list/shopping-edit/shopping-edit.component';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {DropdownDirective} from './model/dropdown.directive';
import { LoginButtonComponent } from './login-button/login-button.component';
import {RecipeService} from './services/recipe.service';
import {ShoppingListService} from './shopping-list/shopping-list.service';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import { RecipeStartComponent } from './recipes/recipe-start/recipe-start.component';
import { RecipeEditComponent } from './recipes/recipe-edit/recipe-edit.component';
import {DataStorageService} from './services/data-storage.service';
import {RecipeEditMainComponent} from './recipes/recipe-edit/recipe-edit-main/recipe-edit-main.component';
import { RecipeEditIngredientsComponent } from './recipes/recipe-edit/recipe-edit-ingredients/recipe-edit-ingredients.component';
import { RecipeEditMethodsComponent } from './recipes/recipe-edit/recipe-edit-methods/recipe-edit-methods.component';
import { SandboxComponent } from './sandbox/sandbox.component';
import { RecipeEditImagesComponent } from './recipes/recipe-edit/recipe-edit-images/recipe-edit-images.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './accounts/sign-up/sign-up.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './accounts/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { SignInComponent } from './accounts/sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { LoadingSpinnerComponent } from './loading-spinner/loading-spinner.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { AddUnitComponent } from './modal/add-unit/add-unit.component';
import { ConfirmDeleteComponent } from './modal/confirm-delete/confirm-delete.component';
import { CommentComponent } from './modal/comment/comment.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    RecipeListComponent,
    RecipeDetailComponent,
    RecipeItemComponent,
    ShoppingListComponent,
    ShoppingEditComponent,
    DropdownDirective,
    LoginButtonComponent,
    RecipeStartComponent,
    RecipeEditComponent,
    RecipeEditMainComponent,
    RecipeEditIngredientsComponent,
    RecipeEditMethodsComponent,
    SandboxComponent,
    RecipeEditImagesComponent,
    SignUpComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent,
    SignInComponent,
    LoadingSpinnerComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    AddUnitComponent,
    ConfirmDeleteComponent,
    CommentComponent
  ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        NgbDropdownModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AutoCompleteModule,
        AccordionModule,
        ButtonModule,
        FileUploadModule,
        GalleriaModule
    ],
  providers: [RecipeService,
    ShoppingListService,
    HttpClient,
    DataStorageService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have a sandbox.component.ts that looks like this:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-sandbox',
  templateUrl: './sandbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sandbox.component.css']
})
export class SandboxComponent implements OnInit {

  images: [
    {
      previewImageSrc: 'images/603RawSteak.jpg',
      thumbnailImageSrc: 'images/603RawSteak.jpg',
      alt: 'Description for Image 1',
      title: 'Title 1'
    },
    {
      previewImageSrc: 'images/75CookedSteak.jpg',
      thumbnailImageSrc: 'images/75CookedSteak.jpg',
      alt: 'Description for Image 2',
      title: 'Title 2'
    }
    ];

  responsiveOptions: any[] = [
    {
      breakpoint: '1024px',
      numVisible: 5
    },
    {
      breakpoint: '768px',
      numVisible: 3
    },
    {
      breakpoint: '560px',
      numVisible: 1
    }
  ];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

I have a sandbox.component.html file that looks like this:

```
<p-galleria [(value)]="images">
  <ng-template pTemplate="item" let-item>
    <img [src]="item.previewImageSrc" style="width: 100%;" />
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="thumbnail" let-item>
    <div class="p-grid p-nogutter p-justify-center">
      <img [src]="item.thumbnailImageSrc" />
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-galleria>
```

I've tried to keep it as simple as possible. But I get the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/sandbox/sandbox.component.html:1:13 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'p-galleria'.
    1. If 'p-galleria' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'p-galleria' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

Other info...

```
C:...>npm view primeng version
9.1.3
```

What's going on?

Comment: Please post the rest of your app.moudle.ts file.  Also, if SandboxComponent is declared in a different module than app.module.ts, post the contents of that too.

Comment: Sometimes when using `ng serve`, if you add a new module you need to stop it and restart it. Especially if it was npm installed.

Comment: Restarting using ng serve was one of the first things I tried. Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: It looks like the imports are good module wise.  Are there any other errors in the console?  I've sometimes had Angular throw a similar error because there was an earlier error stopping the modules from getting imported.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Everything works fine as soon as I remove the Galleria stuff.

Comment: Just been experimenting. If I change the import in app.module.ts to import {GalleriaModule} from 'primeng'; instead of import {GalleriaModule} from 'primeng/galleria'; then the problem is gone. Unfortunately though, this means that ALL primeng modules are loaded. There must be a dependency that is loaded that I need but it isn't in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

It's got to be the way you're binding to value. Looking at the [docs](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/galleria), I don't think that component supports banana-in-a-box binding - so try changing it to this:

```html
<p-galleria [value]="images">
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried these sorts of things as well. The auto complete in my WebStorm IDE can't even find this directive. I'm assuming that I'm importing galleria incorrectly as none of the other directives that are defined in the documentation work either.

Comment: The docs also show it as `<p:galleria>` not `<p-galleria>`